# Correlation of event occurrence in multiple sectors

Tags: correlation, dataset, graph-theory, simultaneity

I have the following problem to analyze:

I divided an area into several sectors (i.e.: S1,S2,S3,…,Sn) and there is an event that can happen in one or more sectors at the same time. I considered a discrete time scale in days (i.e.: D1,D2,D3,…, Dn). For instance, on D1 the event happens twice in S1, once in S2 and thrice in S3. I then recorded the occurrence of the event for all Dn series and got a table:

```
D1  S1
D1  S1
D1  S2
D1  S3
D1  S3
D1  S3
D2  …
…   …
```

What would be the best statistical approach to study if there is any correlation between the event occurrence among the sectors? Can this be done with Graph Theory?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with what you mean by "correlation between the event occurrence among the sectors"? 

For instance, do you mean something like "the event happens in S1 a lot but very rarely in S2"? 

Or something like "Whenever the event happens in S3, it also seems to happen in S4"? 

Or something like "The event only strikes S5 on odd-numbered days?"

Comment: More like it: "Whenever the event happens in S3, it also seems to happen in S4".

Comment: Please add new info as  edits to the post and not only as a comment. Comments are easily overseen and can be deleted!